# Comparison of extra-large subsets of strings

Tags: algorithm, string-comparison, large-data

There is one every-day file from 2000000 to 4000000 strings, which contains unique 15-symbol numbers line by line like this:

```
850025000010145
401115000010152
400025000010166
770025555010152
512498004158752
```

From beginning of current year you have some amount of such files accordingly. So I have to compare every line of today's file with all previous files from beginning of the year and return only that numbers which never meet before in all checked files.

Which language and algorithm should I use? How to implement it?

Comment: Very important thing is: what is your concern? Do you want just to "make it works"? Or you want to do it working "quickly" (and, if yes - then how quickly). Does memory usage matter?

Comment: This is operational task. I have 16Gb allowed memory. Database admin said that it would not work for our db and they asked me "script it" :) runtime not really matter( ofcourse if is it no longer than half of day)

Comment: 1) Do the files contain *only* the numbers, or is there extra content after the identifying numbers? 2) Is your only goal to get a unique set of these numbers ?

Comment: There are **only** numbers line by line and no extra-content

Comment: Yes I need every day get unique set of numbers never meet in previous

Comment: What is the length of a single line? Are the strings of equal length?

Comment: 15 symbols just like I showed in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this without having to write any code beyond a simple script (i.e. bash, Windows batch, Powershell, etc.). There are standard tools that make quick work of this type of thing.

First, you have some number of files that contain from 2 million to 4 million numbers. It's difficult to work with all those files, so the first thing you want to do is create a combined file that's sorted. The simple-minded way to do that is to concatenate all the files into a single file, sort it, and remove duplicates. For example, using the GNU/Linux `cat` and `sort` commands:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 file4 > combined
sort -u combined > combined_sort
```

(The `-u` removes duplicates)

The problem with that approach is that you end up sorting a very large file. Figure 4 million lines at 15 characters, plus newlines, on each line, and almost 100 days of files, and you're working with 7 gigabytes. A whole year's worth of data would be 25 gigabytes. That takes a long time.

So instead, sort each individual file, then merge them:

```
sort -u file1 >file1_sort
sort -u file2 >file2_sort
...
sort -m -u file1 file2 file3 > combined_sorted
```

The `-m` switch merges the already-sorted files.

Now what you have is a sorted list of all the identifiers you've seen so far. You want to compare today's file with that. First, sort today's file:

```
sort -u today >today_sort
```

Now, you can compare the files and output only the files unique to today's file:

```
comm -2 -3 today_sort combined_sort
```

`-2` says suppress lines that occur only in the second file, and `-3` says to suppress lines that are common to both files. So all you'll get is the lines in `today_sort` that don't exist in `combined_sort`.

Now, if you're going to do this every day, then you need to take the output from the `comm` command and merge it with `combined_sort` so that you can use that combined file tomorrow. That prevents you from having to rebuild the `combined_sort` file every day. So:

```
comm -2 -3 today_sort combined_sort > new_values
```

Then:

```
sort -m combined_sort new_values > combined_sort_new
```

You'd probably want to name the file with the date, so you'd have `combined_sort_20140401` and `combined_sort_20140402`, etc.

So if you started at the beginning of the year and wanted to do this every day, your script would look something like:

```
sort -u $todays_file > todays_sorted_file
comm -2 -3 todays_sorted_file $old_combined_sort > todays_uniques
sort -m $old_combined_sort todays_sorted_file > $new_combined_sort
```

`$todays_file`, `$old_combined_sort`, and `$new_combined_sort` are parameters that you pass on the command line. So, if the script was called "daily":

```
daily todays_file.txt all_values_20140101 all_values_20140102
```

Comment: This approach could be combined with [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) to make the whole process automatic.

Answer (score 0):

If you must solve the problem by hands:
 - Convert strings to 64-bit integers. This saves space (2x to 4x) and speeds up - calculations calculations.
 - Sort current file of integers
 - Merge current file with old data file (already sorted), selecting new numbers

Merging step may looks like merge step of MergeSort.
 You can store ranges of numbers in separate files to avoid extra large file sizes.

P.S. I wanted to propose to use bit map, but it will have size about 125 TB

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and which language most suitable for this task?

Comment: Any native language - C, C++, Delphi, and fast VM/CLR languages like Java, C#. I expect that Python, Ruby, Basic, PHP run slower, but limiting factor  - file operations, so these languages may be suitable too. What language are you familiar with?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to build a [prefix tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=usingTries) based on the previous `n-1` files(suppose `n`-th file was created today). The most time-consuming build process has to be done only once. After you build the prefix tree, you can save it as file([google](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+save+data+structure+in+file&oq=java+save+data+structure+in+file) for this topic).

Run the program to check the *new file*:

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("new_file.txt"))) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        if(!tree.contains(line)){
            counter++;
        }else{
                    tree.insert(line);
            }
        line = br.readLine();
    }
}
```

So every day you run this 'pseudo' code, get the unique queries and update the tree.

`contains` takes O(m) time where m is number of chars

`insert` takes O(m) time too

I would suggest Java.

Comment: Why would you use a prefix tree rather than some type of hash table?

Comment: Prefix tree uses less memory than hashtable.

Comment: Prefix tree *can* use less memory. It depends a lot on the distribution of the strings that you're putting into it. When you consider that in this case each node has a high probability of requiring 10 pointers to child nodes, memory savings (if any) will be quite a bit smaller than what you'd get if you were building a prefix tree of English words. In addition, since these are 15-digit numbers, they could be converted to 64-bit integers which require only 8 bytes each. You're not going to get a prefix tree node in 8 bytes.